# get current value of bool in different class Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm making a Flutter app with Firebase and I'm still stuck on the authentication because wether I Sign in or Sign Up, it redirects me to HomePage(). In my auth_page.dart class, I have a bool showLogin which toggles between LoginPage and RegisterPage and I want to access it in my WidgetTree so that when I Sign Up, it redirects me to CreateProfilePage() instead of Home().

Here are the two classes involved :

```
class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthPage({super.key});

  static bool getShowLogin(BuildContext context) {
    final state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AuthPageState>();
    return state?.showLogin ?? true;
  }

  @override
  State<AuthPage> createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

final _authKey = GlobalKey<_AuthPageState>();

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  // show login page initially
  bool showLogin = true;
    void toggleScreens() {
    setState(() {
      showLogin = !showLogin;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showLogin) {
      return LoginPage(showRegisterPage: toggleScreens,);
    }
    else {
      return RegisterPage(showLoginPage: toggleScreens,);
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
class WidgetTree extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetTree({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _WidgetTreeState();
}

class _WidgetTreeState extends State<WidgetTree> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLogin = AuthPage.getShowLogin(context);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Auth().authStateChanges,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return isLogin ? HomePage() : CreateProfilePage();
        }
        else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried putting toggleScreens() directly in AuthPage like so but it simply doesn't toggle the pages anymore

```
  static void toggleScreens(BuildContext context) {
    final state = _authKey.currentState;
    if (state != null) {
      state.setState(() {
        state.showLogin = !state.showLogin;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using implementing getShowLogin() like this in AuthPage but it stills redirects me to HomePage() when I register :

```
  static bool getShowLogin() {
    final state = _authKey.currentState;
    return state?.showLogin ?? true;
  }
```

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some state management and save the  `isLogin` state.

You can go vanilla and implement one yourself, with for example, [ValueNotifier](https://brewyourtech.com/complete-guide-to-valuenotifier-in-flutter/) or you opt with one of the many state management package solutions out there like [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) and [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/), just to mention a couple.

Of course, you can use any of one out there.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you try to access the property of AuthPage from the parent widget which here is WidgetTree. I don't think the context will send you that boolean result:

**so to achieve what you want is better to use a provider or bloc.**

here example code using the provider:

```
class WidgetTree extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetTree({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Auth().authStateChanges,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return authProvider.showLogin ? HomePage() : CreateProfilePage();
        }
        else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**The provider:**

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _showLogin = true;

  bool get showLogin => _showLogin;

  void toggleScreens() {
    _showLogin = !_showLogin;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**The AuthPage**

```
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(
      builder: (context, authProvider, _) {
        if (authProvider.showLogin) {
          return LoginPage(
            showRegisterPage: authProvider.toggleScreens,
          );
        } else {
          return RegisterPage(
            showLoginPage: authProvider.toggleScreens,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

by using the provider you could easily get the boolean result of the toggle screen pretty much like you want.